# Grep outputs multiple lines, need while loop

Tags: bash

I have a script which uses grep to find lines in a text file (ics calendar to be specific)

My script finds a date match, then goes up and down a few lines to copy the summary and start time of the appointment into a separate variable. The problem I have is that I'm going to have multiple appointments at the same time, and I need to run through the whole process for each result in grep.

Example:

```
LINE=`grep -F -n 20130304T232200 /path/to/calendar.ics | cut -f1 d:`
```

And it outputs only the lines, such as
86 89

Then it goes on to capture my other variables, as such:

```
SUMMARYLINE=$(( $LINE + 5 ))
SUMMARY:`sed -n "$SUMMARYLINE"p /path/to/calendar.ics
```

my script runs fine with one output, but it obviously won't work with more than 1 and I need for it to. should I send the grep results into an array? a separate text file to read from? I'm sure I'll need a while loop in here somehow. Need some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `grep` from a loop quite easily:

```
while IFS=':' read -r LINE notused   # avoids the use of cut
do
    # First field is now in $LINE
    # Further processing

done < <(grep -F -n 20130304T232200 /path/to/calendar.ics)
```

However, if the file is not too large then it might be easier to read the whole file into an array and more around that.

Comment: You probably want `while IFS=: read -r LINE notused` (on one line) instead of `for`

Comment: Yup, that is better (typo).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Please help me understand your example better. What is the "notused" there for? When I tried to run this loop the shell told me "syntax error, done unexpected" - I added some of my further processing and it told me on the last line "redirection unexpected"

Comment: @user2134314: The `notused` variable will hold all the fields after the first, which is split around the IFS value.  If we wanted each field then we could have a variable for each field.  Your syntax error implies you might not be using Bash, check your #! line.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was that I was using the wrong shell. But I have another problem now. Doing the script as it is now (basically a simplified version of yours), it just sits there empty not doing anything. If however,if it reads from a text file that grep created, it works. For example: `while read -r line 
do
echo "line is now" $line
sleep 5;
done < "results.log"` works, but ``done < grep -F -n 20130304T232200 $CALENDAR`` just sits there

Comment: sorry, in case it wasn't obvious, I put the /path/to/calendar/ics into the variable $CALENDAR

Comment: and if I break the script because it's just sitting there with ctl+c, it gives me "grep: (standard input): input/output error

Comment: @JonathanMorales: you are missing some syntax.  It should be `done < <(grep ...)`.  Note the space between `< <` and the parentheses.  Otherwise it will try to read from a file called "grep".

Comment: Yep, that was it. The script works now. Thank you to everyone who helped

Answer (score 0):

With your proposed solution, you are reading through the file several times. Using awk, you can do it in one pass:

```
awk -F: -v time=20130304T232200 '
    $1 == "SUMMARY" {summary = substr($0,9)} 
    /^DTSTART/ {start = $2}
    /^END:VEVENT/ && start == time {print summary} 
' calendar.ics
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have never used awk but it seems like an elegant solution. I'll try it with the regular shell scripting first because I'm more familiar with that